# How to inject a variable placeholder `${}` in the spring gateway filters configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

How to inject a variable placeholder `${}` in the spring gateway filters configuration?

```
foo:
  bar: 
    uri: /coucou

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: prefixpath_route
        uri: https://example.org
        filters:
        - PrefixPath=$\\{foo.bar.uri}
```

**NB:**

- I've tried `$\{foo.bar.uri}` and `${foo.bar.uri}`
- I know it's doable programmatically

Comment: `${foo.bar.uri}`?

Comment: @spencergibb it doen't work as well.

Comment: What does "it doen't work as well." mean?

Comment: `        filters:
        - name: PrefixPath
          args:
            prefix: ${foo.bar.uri}` see https://gist.github.com/spencergibb/873f239529f79cb784d4eab3a9ddc4a6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @spencergibb highlighted, it's working by using `args` subproperty:

```
   filters:
    - name: PrefixPath
      args:
        prefix: ${foo.bar.uri}
```

see gist.github.com/spencergibb/873f239529f79cb784d4eab3a9ddc4a6

Answer (score 0):

```
filters:
    - name: PrefixPath
      args:
        prefix: ${foo.bar.uri}
```

and

```
filters:
    - PrefixPath=${foo.bar.uri}
```

should both work, can use actuator to verify

include

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and view `/actuator/gateway/routes`